# NSUserDefaults: registerDefaults -- Adding a New Entry for a Version Upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

My app registers six default color palettes when installed, and the user can add an additional 30.  In an upcoming release, I want to add a seventh color palette to the defaults.  If I just add the seventh to `NSUserDefaults` using `regiserDefaults:` then existing users won't get the new palette.  I expect I'll have to examine the user's `NSUserDefaults` and insert the seventh palette if I don't find it.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You want to add another key to your `NSUserDefaults` dictionary to represent the version number of your app. Check it on startup; if it's not there, you either have a new install or an older version and can add the seventh palette. Then update the version value to the latest version so you don't do it again.

You'll find all sorts of uses for this down the road. In future versions, you won't just check for its presence but also a change in its value.

Comment: Thank you, I can easily see this as a useful mechanism down the road.